# "Er wird das schon gewusst haben."

Tags: tense

> Er wird das schon gewusst haben.

Um was für eine Zeitform handelt es sich hier?

Es scheint das Futur 2 zu sein, aber ich meine, es bezieht auf etwas, das in der Vergangenheit passiert ist. Wann sollte man solche Sätze verwenden und was genau wird damit ausgedrückt?

Comment: Man könnte sich vorstellen, dass diese Form sich aus einer Verkürzung von "Wenn man ihn fragen wird, wird man feststellen, dass er dass schon gewusst haben wird" entstanden sind.

Answer (score 6):

Es handelt sich um Futur II, aber (sehr wahrscheinlich, um es genau zu sagen braucht man den Kontext) nicht in einer temporalen, sondern in einer modalen Funktion, d.h. die Bedeutung ist "Ich gehe davon aus, dass er das gewusst hat".

Das Wort *schon* interpretiere ich hier als Modalpartikel, die anzeigt, dass der Sprecher seine Überzeugung wiedergibt, so wie in "Er wird das schon machen" = "Ich gehe davon aus, dass er das machen wird".

*Schon* kann (wie der Futur II) auch eine temporale Bedeutung haben. Das scheint mir hier weniger wahrscheinlich, definitiv entscheiden kann man es wiederum erst wenn man den Kontext kennt.

Answer (score 5):

Du hast die Zeitform korrekt identifiziert; es ist in der Tat Futur II.

In Sachen *wann*:  [Nutzung](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/future-in-german)

Answer (score 1):

## Die Konstruktion mit *werden* ist keine Zeitform

Es handelt sich um überhaupt keine Zeitform, denn die deutsche Konstruktion mit *werden* ist nicht eine Zeitform, sondern eine Modalkonstruktion. Dies erkennt man daran, dass diese Konstruktion für die Rede über Zukünftiges gar nicht benötigen. Ich kann problemlos sagen:

> Ich gehe morgen zu dir.

Dies kontrastiert fundamental mit der Rede über Vergangenes, wo das Deutsche echte Zeitformen hat, die nicht durch das Präsens ersetzt werden können. Der folgende Satz ist ungrammatikalisch:

> *Ich gehe gestern zu dir.

Stattdessen müssen wir zwingend eine Zeitform verwenden, beispielsweise das Präteritum:

> Ich ging gestern zu dir.

Hier kann also wirklich von einer Zeitform die Rede sein, denn ohne sie ist die Rede über Vergangenes nicht grammatikalisch.

## Was bedeutet die Konstruktion mit *werden* dann?

Allgemein umschreiben liesse sich die Bedeutung vielleicht damit, dass die Konstruktion mit *werden* etwas ausdrückt, was nicht ganz sicher ist und sich noch erweisen muss. Oft liegt es in der Zukunft, aber eben nicht immer.

Mit der Weglassprobe schält sich der Unterschied bei deinem Beispielsatz heraus. Ohne das Wort *werden* wird eine Gewissheit daraus:

> Er hat das schon gewusst.

## Warum spricht man dann vom Futur?

Es hat mit unserer jahrtausendealten Tradition zu tun, dass alle Sprachen in den Begriffen der lateinischen Grammatik beschrieben worden sind.